# OSGi + Weld: FrameworkUtil getBundleContext() returns null

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, apache-felix, weld

I use Apache Felix and weld and I have two classes:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class A {
  private B b= new B();
}

class B {
  private void foo(){
    BundleContext bc= FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
  }
}
```

Object is class A is created by CDI container and I think that's the reason that in class B FrameworkUtil.getBundle returns null. Maybe classloader problem or something like this. Of course I can get the reference to bundle context from A class as Weld injects it. But I don't want to keep this reference inside A and pass it to any other classes. Can I get the reference to bundle context inside B (without taking it from A)? I tried in B:

```
@Inject
BundleContext bundleContext;
```

But it didn't work. It can be important - these classes are in different bundles.

Comment: What makes you believe that CDI and OSGi would work together out of the box? They don't, and that's why there is a project called Pax CDI to provide an integration.

Comment: @hwellmann I know about paxcdi as it's imposible use weld in javase without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the object instance has a type that the CDI container created at runtime by its own custom classloader (by creating a subclass of A).

Instead of using calling

```
BundleContext bc= FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext();
```

try calling

```
BundleContext bc= FrameworkUtil.getBundle(A.class).getBundleContext();
```

In case type A is loaded by the ClassLoader of a bundle, this should work.

Btw.: I recommend not to use Weld, CDI and other technologies within OSGi. They might be integrated, but they often cause lots of pain due to the tricks their tricks that work within Application Servers (where there is only one classloader / app).

Comment: What is strange that FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()) return bundle, but FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext returns null. How to explain it?

Comment: From the javadoc of BundleContext: "A BundleContext object will be created and provided to the bundle associated with this context when it is started using the BundleActivator.start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext) method.". In practice, bundle.getBundleContext() returns null before the bundle gets the STARTING state.

Comment: It's very strange. Because I have two bundles A and B. I install them in order A and B, and start A and B. A bundle contains lib. B contains program. And I get null when I try to get getBundle(classFromB).getBundleContext();

Comment: Are you sure Bundle B is starting / started when you call getBundleContext on it? As much as I remember start function does not throw an exception but you can see that the state of the bundle has not been changed and you can see exception in the log. Even worse if you use equinox as it does not log exceptions to the standard error by default but creates log files with some timestamp in the name in the working dir of equinox.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't start the bundle - I've looked at wrong place.